# How to Search text in dreamweaver for all files in project containing the text '$this->webroot' in CakePHP ctp file?

Tags: cakephp, find, dreamweaver, ctp-file

Hi i am getting one problem in adobe dreamweaver CS3.

Currently dreamweaver not supporing to find any text from `.ctp` file in the entire project. I can see here it supports `.php`, `.js`, `.html` etc. So i am unable to search `.ctp` all files in entire project.

**Ex-**

Suppose i want to find `$this->webroot` in the entire project. When i search it says `Done, Not found in 1366 documents.` But i wrote this text in my `default.ctp` file

**screenshot**
[image]

How to search `.ctp` file. There is no any configuration for change the extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Configure/Opening CakePHP CTP Files in Dreamweaver 3 files that you need to edit:-

- C:\Program Files\(Adobe or Macromedia)\(Adobe )Dreamweaver(version like 8 or cs3)\configuration

Open up “Extensions.txt” and on the first line at the very end add THTML and CTP separated by commas, so the line should read:

- ,MASTER,THTML,CTP:All Documents

Similarly add these two extensions to the “:PHP Files” line.

- PHP,PHP3,PHP4,PHP5,TPL,THTML,CTP:PHP Files

Next open the “DocumentTypes” folder and edit the “MMDocumentTypes.xml” file, just open it up using notepad or wordpad. Search for the line which has an id “PHP_MySQL” and add the THTML/CTP file extensions to both the “winfileextension” and “macfileextension” so the line should read:

- winfileextension=“php,php3,php4,php5,thtml,ctp”
- macfileextension=“php,php3,php4,php5,thtml,ctp”

The final file is another version of the “Extensions.txt” which is located in your “Documents and Settings” Folder in my case this is “C:\Documents and Settings(User_Name)\Application Data(Adobe or Macromedia)(Adobe )Dreamweaver(version like 8 or cs3)\configuration” just add the very same things you inserted earlier in “Extensions.txt” .